From log to inverse hyperbolic tangent function. How?
In order to solve a tough equation I plugged in its expression into Wolfram Alpha. It makes an interesting step to an equation
$$ \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{k/x}}\right)=\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{a}}\right) $$
An in-between WA step, before reaching the inverse hyp. tangent is:
$$ \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{k/x}}\right)=\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{\frac{k/x}{a+k/x}}\sqrt{a+k/x} }\right)=\log\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{ax+k}}[x\sqrt{a}\sqrt{k/x+a}+ax+k]}{k}\right)=\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{a}}\right) $$
x is my variable. a,k constants. Before reaching theinv. hyperb. tan WA states: "which is equaivalent for restricted x,a and k values to.."

The algorithmus switches from a logarithmic function to the inv. hyperb. tangent function without an explanation. This is my attempt to derive the expression.
We know that
$$ \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)=\tanh^{-1}(z) $$
Therefore, I tried to obtain this formulation in my expression. If I extract $\sqrt{a}$, I obtain at the numerator
$$ {\sqrt{a}}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{a}}\right) $$
where the second term in the parenthesis should be my z. However, the denominator of the previous expressio cannot be brought to the form 1-z as for definition of inverse hyperbolic tangent funtion. I started to think to add +1-1 to the denominator in this way
$$ \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{k/x-1+1}}\right)=\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k/x+a}}{\sqrt{a}}\right) $$
How did wolfram obtain the result above at the beginning of the text if it is not mathematically possible?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Definitions_in_terms_of_logarithms

For, say, positive $a$, $k$, $x$, the logarithm value is some real; however, the argument of the inverse-hyp-tangent is greater than $1$, making the value non-real. So, something's wrong. It's hard to say what is wrong, though, without knowing exactly what you fed into WolframAlpha and exactly what it returned.

That equality is not true. You must have made a mistake when using WA. Check https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2F2%29+Log%5B%28Sqrt%5Ba%5D+%2B+Sqrt%5Bk%2Fx+%2B+a%5D%29%2FSqrt%5Bk%2Fx%5D%5D

@gary no the inputs are currently correct

@MarkInt For the reason Blue pointed out, they cannot be. I assume $a>0$ and $k/x>0$. Then $\frac{{\sqrt {k/x + a} }}{{\sqrt a }} > 1$, making the value of the $\tanh^{-1}$ a non-real complex number. However, $\frac{1}{2}\log \left( {\frac{{\sqrt a  + \sqrt {k/x + a} }}{{\sqrt {k/x} }}} \right)$ is a real number, so they cannot be equal. Please provide a link to your WA calculations!

@MarkInt Please provide a link to your WA calculations. I provided one to mine which shows that your statement is incorrect.

@Gary I will reply soon. Stay tuned. Thank you for your interest for the moment

@Gary  I added the omitted parts. See original post now edited. Does it make sense?

@Blue I have written more steps for a better understanding. See editing

Send us the link to the Wolfram Alpha calculations.

sorry for the delay in replying $$r''(t)=-\frac{G M}{r(t)^2}$$  see my previous post   @Gary

To begin with, let us set $f(x) = \tanh(x)$. Consequently, one obtains the following relation:
\begin{align*}
y = f(f^{-1}(y)) = \frac{e^{2f^{-1}(y)} - 1}{e^{2f^{-1}(y)} + 1} & \Longleftrightarrow (e^{2f^{-1}(y)} + 1)y = e^{2f^{-1}(y)} - 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{2f^{-1}(y)}(y - 1) = -(1 + y)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{2f^{-1}(y)} = \frac{1 + y}{1 - y}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1 + y}{1 - y}\right)
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

thanks Atila, it helps out only on a theoretical level but not to solve my specific problem

@MarkInt Would you be able to address the comments below your question?

@Átila Correia  can you have a look at the edited parts in the query?
